# Meterpreter detected by AV

Tags: metasploit

Since January I observed that meterpreter_reverse_https was detected by AV even with the enablestageencoding set to true. I tried to change the signature of the meterpreter and set the handlersslcert to true, without success. After this, I set the SSL option of web_delivery to true but still have the same problem. So, I switched to reverse_tcp_rc4 which worked perfectly until this weekend. Now it is also detected by Symantec.

One point which is important, when I take the source code of the meterpreter in PSH and execute directly in the powershell console, it works! I think that ips detects the signature of the communication between the victim and the web delivery server.

Can some one please explain to me how to resolve the problem? I really need it because I have a meterpreter session which launches periodically with this method.

Comment: AVs are evolutioning too. You must look for other kind of enconding. Did you tried msfvenom using different encodings? You can use multi-encode, like they do [here](https://community.rapid7.com/thread/7668). Maybe if the AV is too sensitive can't be done with msfvenom. The msfvenom is a "n00b" method in the end.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I am not speaking about evad av. This can be done by using poweshell. I am speaking about how to evad ips...

Comment: It's a little unclear to me whether you are getting caught because of the Metasploit traffic over the wire or because of some AV or HIDS-like detection of meterpreter on the test host. But if it is because of the traffic, best I think I could suggest would be to look up the wiki documentation on using Metasploit with "paranoid mode" settings, which covers things like doing reverse https with a pinned certificate (preferably a not-self-signed one) to thwart intercepting proxies. But, well, fundamentally at this point Metasploit's basic C2 habits are very well known and sometimes easy to spot.

Comment: Official documentation on Metasploit/meterpreter "Paranoid Mode" settings: https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/wiki/Meterpreter-Paranoid-Mode

Comment: Evolutioning . Bless you, may your vernacular prosper alongside your technical skills as you dwell in this cornucopic mix of script kiddies and academics who have to deal with them. Also msfvenom is n00b? Please write me some of their migration assembly, I need it for my homework.

Comment: @J.A.K. It is a way of speaking... you know. I put quotes on n00b because is the easiest way to do that.

Comment: sorry for the whole rotomonde, i was a bit tired.  If you want extra stealth, use Veil-Evasion, that works wonders against detection https://www.veil-framework.com/framework/veil-evasion/
In my experience, just injecting the meterpreter with powershell with unicorn will also work https://github.com/trustedsec/unicorn.

Comment: @mostlyinformed, thanks for replgying. You are the only person who understand my problem. I tried metasploid paranoid, but the same problem...

Comment: I tried this method "https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/wiki/Meterpreter-Paranoid-Mode" it's work! But when I try to use web-delivery, AV-IPS detect it !! Some one know the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I find where is the problem, it's the web delivery module of metasploit.
I think that IPS are triggering some HTTP headers of this module.
I bypassed the problem by using multi handler module combine whith a usal apache2 server and it's work! ( you don't need to follow paranoid steps)

If some one know what IPS is exactly triggering and how we can bypass it using web delivery module. Please inform me.

Thanks to all

Comment: Could be a lot of things. Start by having a valid SSL certificate from LetsEncrypt or another trusted CA. A lot of IPSes flag the self signed certificates. Further, use the stageless meterpreter.

Answer (score 0):

Mohammad,

Most AV's are not checking powershell processes for meterpreter sessions at the moment.

I would encourage you to try generating meterpreter droppers from veil-framework as their source code .py, editing the variables, generating an exe with pyinstaller, then trying that.

Happy Hunting.

Comment: Hello, i am not speaking about the dynamic detection but about IPS...